# how to make an image to move in an arch at from the given time like from 6 AM and completes its arch path at 6 PM

Tags: android, animation, canvas

The image of the image that need to be move along in path:

[image]

The sun image that i want to move it in a arch path (roughly sketch in red line) at where it begins when the time is at 6 A.M so it completes its arch path at 6 pm. for example if the user opens the app at 3 pm then the image should be in its position where it should be in 3 p.m,like this way arch should be completed at 6 P.M

Comment: what is that for a control?? a Canvas???

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator#ofFloat` with a `Path` parameter